# Method to handle multiple "Is" statements

Tags: c#, extension-methods

In my current code, I am testing for an object's type using `if/else if` & `is`:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else if (value is int)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else if (value is string)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else if (value is bool)
        {
            //do something
        }
       Type type = value.GetType();
       throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported type [" + type.Name + "]");
    }
```

Rather than having a long list of `else if`, I tried to condense all of the `is` statements using an [`Extension Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), but to no avail.

Here is my attempt at the `Extension Method`:

```
public static class Extensions
    {
        public static bool Is<T>(this T t, params T[] values)
        {
            return values.Equals(t.GetType());
        }
    }
```

and the method:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else if (value.Is<object>(int, string, bool))
        {
            //do something
        }

        Type type = value.GetType();
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported type [" + type.Name + "]");
  }
```

Does anyone know why this is failing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why don't you create multiple converters for the various types?

Comment: don't you mean `.Contains`, not `.Equals`?

Comment: Shouldn't you have `return values.Contains(t.GetType());` instead of `return values.Equals(t.GetType());`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use `||`? E.g. `if (value is SolidColorBrush || value is LinearGradientBrush || …)`.

Comment: @svick ideally, I would like to pass the Type into the extension. Currently, it is giving me an error saying `SolidColorBrush is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'`.

Comment: you need to use `typeof(SolidColorBrush)` to get a variable containing the type

Comment: Also, wouldn't `value is Brush` work for you? (`Brush` is the base class of all those types.) And do you know that `LinearGradientBrush` and `RadialGradientBrush` inherit from `GradientBrush`?

Comment: VERY BAD examples on my part... made changes to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass it the types, not the class names. You should also use `Contains` instead of `Equals`:

```
public static bool IsAny(this object obj, params Type[] types)
{
    return types.Contains(obj.GetType());
}

if(value.IsAny(typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(LinearGradientBrush), typeof(GradientBrush), typeof(RadialGradientBrush)))
{
}
```

`Contains` matches the type exactly, so you might want to is `IsSubclassOf` or `IsAssignableFrom` instead

e.g

```
return types.Any(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()));
```

Comment: Note that this has slightly different behavior - You'd need to use `type.IsAssignableFrom` to get the same behavior as the current `is` based version.

Comment: Note that in this case if you pass a type that is a supertype of the object itself your method returns false, whereas a bunch of chained `is` operators would return true.  You'd need to use `IsAssignableFrom` instead of straight equality to get the same behavior.

Comment: Actually, I _think_ the `IsAssignableFrom` usage is backwards here. I _think_ you want `t.IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType())`. EDIT: And, if Dom is willing to write them, you _could_ create a series of generic overloads so you can call it like `obj.IsAny<SolidColorBrush, LinearGradientBrush, GradientBrush, RadialGradientBrush>()` and avoid all the `typeof` in the call.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - I don't think so -`superType.IsAssignableFrom(subType)` returns true, like `instanceOfSubtype is SuperType` does.

Comment: Yeah, but don't you have it written right now as `subClass.IsAssignableFrom(baseClass)` as in `subClass is baseClass`?

Answer (score 4):

So you have several problems here.  The first of which is the line: `values.Equals(t.GetType())`.  You're not checking each of the values of the collection, you're checking if the collection as a whole is equal to the one type.  Since one is an `object[]` and one is a `Type` they'll never be equal.  You need to check if *Any* of the values in the collection are equal to the type.

Next, you don't want the parameters to be a bunch of objects, you want them to be a bunch of Types.

Here is a better solution:

```
public static bool IsAny(this object obj, params Type[] types)
{
    return types.Any(type => type.IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()));
}
```

You would then use it like:

```
bool b = "a".IsAny(typeof(int), typeof(double), typeof(MyClass));
```

Comment: You have got it slightly wrong. It should be the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game, but if you want to keep the generic syntax and avoid the usage of `typeof`, you can create a series of generic overloads with an increasing number of generic parameters up to some reasonable limit (just like `Action<,,,>` and `Func<,,,>` do)

```
public static bool Is<T1, T2, T3, T4>(this object obj)
{
    return  obj is T1 ||
            obj is T2 ||
            obj is T3 ||
            obj is T4;
}
```

And proceed to write overloads for other numbers of `T1` through `TN` (where `N` is the maximum number that you'd expect.

Your usage then looks like:

```
else if (value.Is<SolidColorBrush, LinearGradientBrush, GradientBrush, RadialGradientBrush>())
```